# Acer Aspire-R7 WiFi

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, acer, aspire

Will Ubuntu ever support the Acer Aspire-R7? It uses a custom Broadcom chipset. I even tried using an external USB 'EnGenius Wireless N', but the driver crashes. I give up at this point. I don't have an ethernet port and don't want to switch to another Linux distribution. Does the Beta support this chipset or is Ubuntu and Acer R7 a deadend?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: This has been handled in depth at [http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx

Answer (score 1):

Actually I really don't know what is your pc's properties. But my laptop has Broadcom wifi adapter. When I installed ubuntu my wifi card wasn't working, i connect it to internet with an ethernet cable than let it to install additional devices which Broadcom listed in it. After installation it works like a charm. If not, you can manually install broadcom-sta-drivers to make it work.

Have a nice day..